# Using hashed passwords from openLDAP for authentication in Mikrotik hotspot with intermediate step as FreeRADIUS

Tags: openldap, freeradius

lets say I have chain Mikrotik Hotspot-FreeRADIUS0-OpenLDAP and I want authenticate users stored in LDAP directory in Hotspot. Until now I have all passwords in plaintext and eveything works fine, but now I want to save these passwords in hash format (probably SSHA, default ldappasswd option). I suppose I have to enable option for hash passwords in all steps this chain, but I didn't find anywhere how to enable it in FreeRADIUS. Thanks for your help

Comment: Which version of FreeRADIUS? How you do it changes depending on which version you're running.

Comment: Currently I'm using version 3.0.4 of FreeRADIUS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `raddb/mods-available/ldap`

```
ldap {
    ...
    update {
        control:Password-With-Header := '<your ldap password attribute>'
    }
    ...
}
```

In `raddb/sites-available/default` or `raddb/sites-available/inner-tunnel`

```
authorize {
    ...
    eap
    ldap
    pap
    ...
}
```

In your LDAP password attributes add the appropriate header before the password value.

Complete list of headers is here: https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.0.x/src/modules/rlm_pap/rlm_pap.c#L76

When the LDAP module runs it'll look for your password attribute, and store it in the FreeRADIUS internal `Password-With-Header` attribute.

When the PAP module runs, it'll search for the `Password-With-Header` attribute, look through the predefined list of header names to see if any match the start of the `Password-With-Header` value.

If one does, the PAP module will remove the header, convert from base64/hex as appropriate, hash the password the user provided with the same digest algorithm and salt, and compare the result.

If the hashes match, the pap module returns ok, and authentication continues, else the pap module will return reject and authentication will fail.

In order for this to work you need to be using the `EAP-TTLS-PAP` EAP-Type (for WPA2-Enterprise) or just plain `PAP` (for webportal logins).